# gitlab pipeline fail to use aws service

Tags: gitlab-ci, aws-cli

This error show "An HTTP Client raised an unhandled exception: Invalid header value b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=********************************************" in gitlab ci pipeline

I am already create AWS varible in gitlab ci and created s3 bucket in aws console. my gitlab ci config is

upload to s3:
image:
name: banst/awscli
entrypoint: [""]
script:
- aws configure set region us-east-1
- aws s3 ls

please answer me!

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing?

Next I will present the step by step to list the buckets through gitlab-ci.

**1-** Create a repository in gitlab.

**2-** In your GitLab project, go to **Settings > CI/CD**. Set the following **CI/CD variables**:
**AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:** Your Access key ID.

**AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:** Your secret access key.

**AWS_DEFAULT_REGION:** Your region code.
[Variables of Aws' credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FNkl.png)

**3-** Create a file called **.gitlab-ci.yml** in your repository. I left attached an example of the pipeline with listing and creating buckets in S3. Aws has as a rule that the name of the **bucket is unique** in all accounts, so be creative or specific in the name.
[File of gitlab.ci - Pipeline S3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cAIG.png)

**4-** When you commit to the repository, it will open a pipeline. I left the **steps manually**, so I need to press to perform the step.[Steps of the Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60ZLM.png)

I hope I have helped, if you have any questions I am at your disposal.

```html
  - build_s3
  - create_s3

create-s3:
  stage: create_s3
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  when: manual
  script:
    - aws s3api create-bucket --bucket my-bucket-stackoverflow-mms --region us-east-1

build-s3:
  stage: build_s3
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  when: manual
  script:
    - aws s3 ls
```